# What does the size: attribute do in this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 10 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

I have used this code and assumed it would vary the size of the gravatar, however it seems to have no affect on it?  Am I missing something?  I have also tried to change the value in the view to:

```
<%= gravatar_for @user, size: 10 %>
<%= @user.name %>
```

To see if this changes anything, to no avail.

Comment: How does the generated HTML look like? The `s=` option of gravatar does work.

Comment: @ThiefMaster `<img alt="Rails Tutorial" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/bebfcf57d6d8277d806a9ef3385c078d.png" />` this is the generated html

Comment: My fault I hadn't added the `?s=#{size}` part to the gravatar_url thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

assuming your helper module is as below

```
module UsersHelper

   # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })

    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)

    size = options[:size]

    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"

    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")

  end

end
```

then pass in your size in the view

```
<%= gravatar_for @user, :size => 30 %>
```